# Why can't I set my QDialog to have no sizeGrip?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

According to the QT4 docs QDialog's sizeGrip is disabled by default, however mine has one anyways. So I try running setSizeGripEnabled(false) and I still have one. So, something else must be causing this, but I don't know what. If it matters my dialog box currently has no parent because I'm designing/testing it. I don't see why that should matter, but just mentioning it in case it does for some reason. Here's my full code:

```
#include "QtGui"
//#include "clposter.h"

void add_new_account()
{
    // CHECK::Make sure this process is destroyed when it's supposed to be
    // TODO::connect signals to slots
    //
    // Create Dialog box to add user account
    QDialog *accountDialog = new QDialog();
    accountDialog->setModal(true);
    accountDialog->setWindowTitle("Add New Account");
    accountDialog->setSizeGripEnabled(false);

    // Create Main Layout
    QVBoxLayout *mainVBox = new QVBoxLayout(accountDialog);

    QLabel *accountNameLabel = new QLabel(accountDialog);
    accountNameLabel->setText("Account:");
    QLineEdit *accountName = new QLineEdit(accountDialog);
    accountName->setMinimumWidth(250);
    QLabel *accountPassLabel = new QLabel(accountDialog);
    accountPassLabel->setText("Password:");
    QLineEdit *accountPass = new QLineEdit(accountDialog);
    accountPass->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);

    // NOTE::May want to use standard dialog buttons instead
    QPushButton *okButton = new QPushButton("Ok", accountDialog);
    QPushButton *cancelButton = new QPushButton("Cancel", accountDialog);

    // Connect signals to slots

    // Set layout
    // CHECK::Should accountDialog be the parent for these? I get a warning that they cannot be set
    //        because accountDialog already has a layout, which is expected, but I want them to
    //        automatically be deleted when accountDialog is so it makes sense to make it the parent.
    QVBoxLayout *labelsVBox = new QVBoxLayout(accountDialog);
    labelsVBox->addWidget(accountNameLabel);
    labelsVBox->addWidget(accountPassLabel);

    QVBoxLayout *lineEditsVBox = new QVBoxLayout(accountDialog);
    lineEditsVBox->addWidget(accountName);
    lineEditsVBox->addWidget(accountPass);

    QHBoxLayout *topHBox = new QHBoxLayout(accountDialog);
    topHBox->addLayout(labelsVBox);
    topHBox->addLayout(lineEditsVBox);

    QHBoxLayout *buttonHBox = new QHBoxLayout(accountDialog);
    buttonHBox->addStretch();
    buttonHBox->addWidget(okButton);
    buttonHBox->addWidget(cancelButton);

    mainVBox->addLayout(topHBox);
    mainVBox->addLayout(buttonHBox);

    accountDialog->setLayout(mainVBox);

    // Show Dialog
    accountDialog->exec();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    //CLPoster mainWin;
    //mainWin.show();
    add_new_account();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you on? Is the dialog resizable when using setFixedSize, or is just the grip painted, without being functional?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the parent should not affect anything.

You can get around this by setting the Dialog to a fixed size by using setFixedSize(width, height);

However this is definitely a work around.

Comment: I've tried that too and it doesn't work :(. I think I might be stuck.